# 3 Is there anyway to insert new lines in-between two patterns

Tags: shell, unix, sed, grep

Is there anyway to insert new lines in-between 2 specific patterns of characters? I want to insert a new line every time "`butterfly`" occurs in a text file, however I want this new line to be inserted between the "`butter`" and "`fly`". For example `butter\nfly`

I also want to find the length of each line after splitting.

Eg:

if textfile contains:

fgsccgewvdhbejbecbecbou**butterfly**bvdcvhkebcjl
vdjchvhecbih**butterfly**glehblejkbedk**butterfly**r

Then, I want a result like the following:

```
29 fgsccgewvdhbejbecbecboubutter       
33 flybvdcvhkebcjlvdjchvhecbihbutter        
22 flyglehblejkbedkbutter         
4 flyr
```

I believe one way to tackle it would be to insert a new line using "`sed`" everywhere "`butter`" occurs and is followed by "`fly`". Strip out all blank line using `grep` with a -v flag. Then get the length of each line. However, even after trying a lot, I am unable to get the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Sed 's' sub-command + awk can work together:

```
sed -e "s/butterfly/butter\\nfly/g" < input.txt | awk '{ print length, $0 }'
```

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU sed & bash):

```
sed -Ez 's/\n//g;s/(butter)(fly)/\1\n\2/g;s/^.*$/l=&;printf "%d %s\n" ${#l} &/meg' file
```

Slurp the file into memory using the `-z` sed option. Remove all existing newlines and then insert new ones between `butter` and `fly`. Using the `m`, `g` and `e` flags of the sed substitute command, split into separate lines and using bash make a variable `l` and via `printf` print the required format.